# How to get Buys and sells of a token on a Dex

Tags: web3js, web3.py, pancakeswap

Im trying to rebuild a simple app that gives me the latest buys or sells of a token on pancakeswap.

Im using this code here and it kind of works:

```
def handle_event(event):
    
    print(Web3.toJSON(event))
  

async def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            handle_event(event)
        await asyncio.sleep(poll_interval)

def main():
    event_filter = myContract.events.Transfer.createFilter(fromBlock="latest")
    #block_filter = web3.eth.filter('latest')
    #tx_filter = web3.eth.filter('pending')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.gather(
                #log_loop(block_filter, 2),
                #log_loop(tx_filter, 2)))
                log_loop(event_filter, 2)))
    finally:
        loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When running this code I get following response:

```
{"args": {"from": "0xC58e952b2395e48b89f3A2cBC29A7d06EE101236", "to": "0x8fBd8037bF3E5C2008E335588C3cBB319F9C2A30", "value": 199302021}, "event": "Transfer", "logIndex": 154, "transactionIndex": 38, "transactionHash": "0xf9164398a9ca8036ddb7d8c01b701ea64b69c19176f7cca83eb9bbaaea61dfca", "address": "0x6615a63c260be84974166a5EDDfF223cE292CF3D", "blockHash": "0xc7ddc76fbf22caa30649edbaef3438a0a037787755550ef620365462263a574b", "blockNumber": 15745512}
```

In this example I bought xyz token with wbnb,
'from' represents the address of the liquidityPair and 'to' is my personal address that bought xyzToken.

Now the problem is that for this specific token there are 2 LP pairs, 1 is xyzTOken and WBNB, the other 1 is xyzToken and BUSD.

When doing test buys sometimes the 'from' address is the WBNB/xyz token and than i get as 'from' address Busd/xyzToken.

I tried to fix this with an if esle statement like so:

```
getBuy = Web3.toJSON(event['args']['from'])
    if getBuy == '0xC58e952b2395e48b89f3A2cBC29A7d06EE101236':
        print('BUY: ', event['args']['value'] ,Fore.GREEN)
    else:
        print('SELL: ', event['args']['value'] ,Fore.RED)
```

but there got to be a better way to solve this, sometthing more dynamic where I can use this for ever token even without knowing the LP address

Answer (score 0):

No1 you need to add the particular pair in the script.. for a buybot portfolio I built a month back, the script (Telegram bot) will ask for a ca input, then get the pairs and you choose which of the pairs then it adds it in the database and starts threading for new buys..

2: if the recipient is the transaction sender then it's a buy...
if transaction_sener == recipient:
#do something

These two steps will solve the problem. you can check out t.me/cryptowisechannel to get an implemented example